# How to set width of div to grandparent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table based on flexbox. The container has flex-direction set to row and a flex-item per column. Now i need a way to highlight all items on a row. Since each row is dispersed over multiple flex-items (columns) i tried to create a div which highlights the row. The div is created at the first column with the follwing styling ;

```
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 65365;
  width: 400px;
  top: -1px;
  height: 27px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #111;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Since the table can resizie dynamically i need to set the size of the div highlighting the row relative to the size of the grandparent div, fr-flex-table.

To make it more clear i created a codepen.io example. I was not able to integrate it into this question so therefore an external link to the example.

https://codepen.io/poundfoolish/pen/ExPxEgb

Is there a way to change the width of the div based on the grandparents div width ?

Comment: something like this? `$('.fr-row-selector').css('width', $('.fr-flex-table').css('width'));`

Comment: Assume this is a jQuery selector ? If so, it probably will work. But not a possibility for me.

Comment: ah didnt know that wasn't an option, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If columns count is fixed then you can do some thing like this

Suppose for 3 columns

```
width: calc(calc(100% * 3) + 2px) // 2px just added so that it will cover table borders
```

Comment: Almost perfect. The nested calc functions do not work in Less. Nesting is also not required, it can be done with one Calc function call. In Less this worked for me;
```width: calc(~"100% * 3 + 4px");```